# Конвертирование строк c#

Tags: c#

Как конвертировать строку в `c#` чтобы кириллица нормально отображалась?
Пример:
`"\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442"` должно стать `"привет"`.

Comment: А откуда у вас эта строка взялась?

Comment: Со StreamReader.

Comment: Так это и есть «привет». Проверка: http://ideone.com/e6oXch

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы в TextBox отображалось "привет", а не это.

Comment: Эээ, а как вы отправляете это в `TextBox`? Если в текстбокс попадают слеши, тогда ваша строка вовсе не такая, а `"\\u043f\\u0440\\u0438\\u0432\\u0435\\u0442"`. И тогда вопрос, откуда она взялась. (Проверка: http://ideone.com/e6oXch)

Comment: Спасибо, а как можно заменить "\\" на "\"?

Comment: Не, заменить не удастся, в строке у вас нет двух слешей, это лишь она так выглядит в исходнике. Проблема не тут, проблема раньше. Расскажите, откуда у вас взялась эта строка в `StreamReader`'е.

Comment: C `(HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();`. Оттуда и `StreamReader`.

Comment: Ааа! А не часть ли это javascript-кода?

Comment: Это ответ от сервера в формате json.

Comment: Ооооо! Тогда всё становится на свои места. Для разбора формата JSON вам нужен JSON-парсер, а не ручной разбор. Например, [JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).

Comment: Вам нужно взять _весь_ JSON-ответ и распарсить его в объект. И работать уже с объектом.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Работает.

Comment: О, ну вот и хорошо. Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Как показало расследование в комментариях, строка является фрагментом JSON-ответа сервера.

Для этого случая правильным подходом является считывание всего JSON-ответа и разбор его при помощи JSON-парсера — например, JSON.NET ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/), [документация](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)).